# portable java application

Tags: java, android

In your answer

[Writing a portable Java application using JOGL and Android OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617524/writing-a-portable-java-application-using-jogl-and-android-opengl/1627609#1627609)

can you please tell me how to automatically work out which platform you are running on.

Thank you very much

Comment: Strange way to ask a question on SOF

Answer (score 0):

The normal way that a Java application finds out what platform it is running on is to look at the system Properties.  The javadoc for [`System.getProperties()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) lists the standard properties that a JVM should set.